# nodejs heroku crushed (h10 error) (defined_crc)

Tags: node.js, heroku

Without changing any code I am getting an error where I previously my web app deployed to heroku had succeed. Specifically, I could see my web app via ~~~~.herokuapp.com.

My environment: OSX ElCapitan and NodeJS.

Now I get "Application Error".

`heroku logs -t` output:

```
2016-04-07T14:19:55.963042+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=study-event-app.herokuapp.com request_id=833eb1b0-5719-4bb9-9a61-fd6b9d687fdd fwd="131.113.37.94" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
    2016-04-07T14:19:56.611874+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=study-event-app.herokuapp.com request_id=d12f9e7c-2cf5-4d3a-95c1-61bc903b4511 fwd="131.113.37.94" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
    2016-04-07T14:21:40.323547+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2016-04-07T14:21:46.502676+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node ./bin/www`
    2016-04-07T14:21:49.111984+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:341
    2016-04-07T14:21:49.111997+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
    2016-04-07T14:21:49.111998+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
    2016-04-07T14:21:49.111998+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2016-04-07T14:21:49.112023+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module './define_crc'
    2016-04-07T14:21:49.112031+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
    2016-04-07T14:21:49.112032+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    2016-04-07T14:21:49.112033+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    2016-04-07T14:21:49.112033+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    2016-04-07T14:21:49.112040+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/crc/lib/crc1.js:5:19)
    2016-04-07T14:21:49.112041+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    2016-04-07T14:21:49.112042+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    2016-04-07T14:21:49.112042+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    2016-04-07T14:21:49.112043+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    2016-04-07T14:21:49.112048+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    2016-04-07T14:21:50.065610+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
    2016-04-07T14:21:50.103251+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

and `heroku ps` output is following:

```
Free quota left: 17h 59m
=== web (Free): node ./bin/www (1)
web.1: crashed 2016/04/07 23:21:50 +0900 (~ 7m ago)
```

I tried `heroku restart web.1 --app 'app-name'` but this command didn't solve the problem. It is displayed: `Error: Cannot find module './define_crc'`, but i didn't require this module.

I need advice on how to troubleshoot this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try cleaning your nodes_module cache on heroku :

```
heroku config:set NODEMODULESCACHE=false
git commit -a -m "rebuild" --allow-empty
git push heroku master
heroku config:unset NODEMODULESCACHE
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, are all the following conditions met ?

- you specify a node and npm version in your package.json file (see `engines`)
- all of your dependencies are declared in your package.json
- you use npm `shrinkwrap` to lock down all packages' version